# Address the problem of heteroscedasticity

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity, granger-causality

I have 15 variables.

The aim is to conduct Granger's causality test. I want to see whether I should Use log for all my variables. In order to check for the occurrence of heteroscedasticity, do I regress all the variable together or do I regress one single independent with the dependent and then check for its $\chi^2$?